# Can I get a Schengen visa using a Ukrainian-issued refugee travel document?

Tags: visas, schengen, refugees

Am I able to get a Schengen visa using a 1951 Convention refugee travel document issued to me by Ukraine?

Answer (score 3):

Can you apply for a Schengen visa? Yes.

Will you get a Schengen visa? Probably not, unless you can show *very* strong ties to Ukraine, such as a highly-paid job, a piece of real estate, marriage to a local citizen, etc. Considering the latest refugee-related events it is most likely hard to convince the authorities you will actually leave at the end of your stay.